# django/python how come the module that ran this code isn't listed in the traceback?

Tags: python, django

Sometimes, maybe about 30-40% of the time when I get a traceback, the actual file that read the code isn't listed, why would that be?

Take this traceback for example..

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/jeff/Django/langalang/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/jeff/Django/langalang/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 312, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/jeff/Django/langalang/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/jeff/Django/langalang/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/jeff/Django/langalang/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 86, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named captcha
```

I deduced after a minute of thinking that it must be from my settings.py, but it doesn't actually say that anywhere in the trace. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've shown is using a lot of generics to try to import a module and generic code by its very nature has no business in knowing what your module name actually is.

In other examples you may find, its because you've gone down a rabbit hole. The place where the actual error is is so far away from your own code that the stack trace is showing too many steps past your own line of code.

> I deduced after a minute of thinking that it must be from my settings.py, but it doesn't actually say that anywhere in the trace. Why?

It actually does give you a hint at this

```
File "/home/jeff/Django/langalang/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

It mentions its trying to create the `INSTALLED_APPS` about half way up the trace